# Python setup failed код ошибки: 0x80072efd

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить новую версию python'a, но он не хочет устанавливаться и выдает вот такую ошибку. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня стоит Windows 7 Максимальная. Не могу понять в чём проблема, а в интернете информации про это мало, к большому сожалению.

Comment: Может, заглянуть в предлагаемый лог?

Comment: @mkkik Да, могу

Comment: @mkkik Я открыл его, но ничего в нём не понимаю, вот ссылка на лог - https://pastebin.com/kifA5K5U

Comment: С вашего ПК, на котором вы устанавливаете pyhton,  есть доступ к https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/amd64/ ?

Comment: @strawdog Да, ссылка открывается

Comment: @David, значит проверьте брандмауэр, чтобы установщику было разрешено ходить в интернет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установщик пытается скачать другие пакеты из интернета, но у него не получается

```
[0ECC:1124][2019-09-16T17:38:03]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Failed to send request to URL: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/amd64/core.msi, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0ECC:1124][2019-09-16T17:38:03]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Unknown HTTP status code 0, returned from URL: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/amd64/core.msi
[0ECC:1124][2019-09-16T17:38:03]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/amd64/core.msi' to: 'C:\Windows\Temp\{15CFE69B-BC15-43F2-9EBF-425C2A44700D}\core_JustForMe'
[0ECC:1124][2019-09-16T17:38:03]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/amd64/core.msi' to working path: 'C:\Windows\Temp\{15CFE69B-BC15-43F2-9EBF-425C2A44700D}\core_JustForMe'
```

Возможные решения

1. Запустить от имени администратора
2. Проверить firewall (если программа запрашивала доступ в сеть)
3. Скачать другой инсталлятор (MSI/EXE)
4. Отключить антивирус на время установки

Может, просто временный сетевой глюк был

Comment: Я попробовал первые 2 пункта, к сожалению не помогает

Comment: Еще может быть проблема в антивирусе, попробуйте его отключить на время установки

Answer (score 1):

Если не получается, то попробуйте установку через Windows Installer. Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой при установке версии 2.7.5. Установить её получилось через вышеупомянутый инсталлер.

Answer (score 0):

Решение пробемы:

Заходите в панель управления > свойства браузера > вкладка дополнительно >

Далее у меня было выключено эти 2-ва пункта, которые на картинке ниже. Включаете их, применяете изменения, и готово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]